# get always 10 numbers from randoms - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I need help with my code. I want to get 10 random numbers every time it rolls and it can't have duplicated, this is my code:

```
for(let j = 1; j <= 21; j++) {
    const number = (Math.floor((Math.random() * j) + 1))
    const genNumber = array.indexOf(number);
    if (genNumber === -1) {
        array.push(number);
    }
}
```

I have no idea how I can get exactly 10 numbers every time, anyway it can be written with js or jquery it doesnt metter for me. Hope I can get help here.

Comment: Why does your `for ...` loop go until 21? Have you considered dropping it to 10?

Comment: using a while loop and continuing until the size of array is 10

Comment: its 21 becasue im creating a memory game and i have at the moemnt 21 pictures and it randomly add different images

Comment: You are confusing the loop counter (21, which should be the max number to get) with the amount of numbers to generate, which should be 10.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your code is intended to do, but to get exactly 10 unique random numbers I'd use a Set and loop until it's filled. I have no idea why you loop 21 times for 10 items though...

```js
let s = new Set();
while (s.size < 10) {
  s.add((Math.floor(Math.random() * 21 /* ??? */) + 1));
}

console.log([...s]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but instead of using a for loop, use a while loop that continues as long as there are less than 10 things in the array:

```js
const array = [];
const j = 21; // Pick numbers between 1 and 21 (inclusive)

while (array.length < 10) {
    const number = (Math.floor((Math.random() * j) + 1))
    const genNumber = array.indexOf(number);
    if (genNumber === -1) {
        array.push(number);
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: That works for me , im glad for your help , i forget about while loop , thanks you so much :)